# Params value couldn't be saved after creating form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

currently I can submit and create my form. However, the problem is there is one field in my table that has a nill value, which is the created_by column. I don't know where its value is passed to since it doesn't throw me any error. I guess, somehow, my create method couldn't pass the value of current_user.id into the field created_by in the commodity group table, and I think I have set up correctly the relationship between user and commodity group. 
Basically, all I want is if a user creates a commodity group, his id will be saved into the column created_by in the table commodity group, and if he updates the info on a commodity group, his id will be saved into the column update_by so that I can retrieve his name or email into the view by doing something like this:

```
<p>
Created by: <%= @commodity_group.user.name %> 
Updated by: <%= @commodity_group.user.name %>
</p>
```

**Update:** I don't know somehow the current_user.id can be saved into the column created_by now. However, when I call <%= @commodity_group.user.name %>, I get this error:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Here are all the files:

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  include Filterable

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :history
  has_secure_password
  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :activities
  has_many :pricing_histories

  has_many :commodity_groups_created, class_name: 'CommodityGroup',
                                      foreign_key: :created_by
  has_many :commodity_groups_updated, class_name: 'CommodityGroup',
                                      foreign_key: :updated_by
end
```

**commodity_group.rb:**

```
class CommodityGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :code, use: :history

  belongs_to :created_user,
             class_name: 'User',
             primary_key: :id,
             foreign_key: :created_by
  belongs_to :updated_user,
             class_name: 'User',
             primary_key: :id,
             foreign_key: :updated_by

  validates_presence_of :code
  validates_presence_of :name
  # validates_presence_of :user
end
```

**commodity_groups/_form.html.haml**:

```
%div.page-content-wrapper
  %div.page-content
    = render 'header'
    %div.row
      .col-md-12
        .portlet.light.form-fit
          .portlet-title
            - if defined? title
              .caption
                %i.icon-user.font-blue-hoki
                %span.caption-subject.font-blue-hoki.bold.uppercase
                  = title
          .portlet-body.form
            = form_for @commodity_group, html: {class: 'form-horizontal form-bordered form-label-stripped'} do |f|
              .form-body
                .form-group
                  %label.control-label.col-md-3 Code
                  .col-md-9
                    = f.text_field :code, placeholder: 'Code', class: 'form-control'
                .form-group.last
                  %label.control-label.col-md-3 Name
                  .col-md-9
                    = f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', class: 'form-control'
              .form-actions
                .row
                  .col-md-offset-3.col-md-9
                    %button.btn.green{:type => 'submit'}
                      %i.fa.fa-check
                      Submit
                    = link_to "Cancel", locations_path, class: 'btn default'
```

**commodity_groups_controller.rb:**

```
class CommodityGroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commodity_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /commodity_groups
  def index
    @commodity_groups = CommodityGroup.all
  end

  # GET /commodity_groups/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /commodity_groups/new
  def new
    @commodity_group = current_user.commodity_groups_created.build
  end

  # GET /commodity_groups/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /commodity_groups
  def create
    @commodity_group = current_user.commodity_groups_created.create(commodity_group_params)

    if @commodity_group.save!
      redirect_to commodity_groups_path, notice: init_message(:success, t('message.new_success', page_name: t('page_name.commodity_group')))
    else
      redirect_to new_commodity_group_path, notice: init_message(:error, t('message.new_error', page_name: t('page_name.commodity_group')))
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /commodity_groups/1
  def update
    if @commodity_group.update(commodity_group_params)
      @commodity_group.update_columns(created_by: current_user.id)

      redirect_to @commodity_group, notice: 'Commodity group was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /commodity_groups/1
  def destroy
    @commodity_group.destroy
    redirect_to commodity_groups_url, notice: 'Commodity group was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_commodity_group
      @commodity_group = CommodityGroup.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def commodity_group_params
      params.require(:commodity_group).permit(:code, :name, :created_by, :updated_by, :slug)
    end
end
```

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: You're using save! Which silences errors. Remove the exclamation point and you may see the error that caused the failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the commodity_object is saved correctly with the user id's.

**If no,**

Please upload the form and params that were being sent from the form.

**If yes,**

In the **commodity_group.rb** file you have given the two `belongs_to` relations with the same code which is wrong, so it gets confused in what relation does it take for `created_by and updated_by`.

Change the file as follows,

```
class CommodityGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :code, use: :history

  belongs_to :created_user,
             class_name: 'User',
             primary_key: :id,
             foreign_key: :created_by
  belongs_to :updated_user,
             class_name: 'User',
             primary_key: :id,
             foreign_key: :updated_by

  validates_presence_of :code
  validates_presence_of :name
  # validates_presence_of :user
end
```

**watch carefully the two belongs_to names.**
Now you can call using,

```
<%= @commodity_group.created_user.name %> 
<%= @commodity_group.updated_user.name %>
```

The created_user and updated_user will be taken based on the assosciations.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I've just edited my commodity_group.rb file, and it works. However, I am wondering how can I update the created_by column in the update action. I've updated my commodity_groups_controller.rb, could you please take a quick look at it?